# php mysql query loading data from previous query

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I am writing a script to add `users` to a database.
Simultaniously a new registered user is always signing up for a `course`.

So what I've got is the first part of my script that basically does this

(removed a lot of user-input checks here to simplify - all variables defined before):

```
$user =
"INSERT INTO users (
    name,
    firstname,
    date_of_birth,
    email,
    # etc ...
) VALUES (
    '$name',
    '$firstname',
    '$date_of_birth',
    '$email',
    # etc ...
)";

if (mysql_query($user) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['infotext'] = "User added successfully";
    $success_user = 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['infotext'] = "Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error();
}
```

This works so far.
In the database the is a `user_nr` that's set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
# get the users data 
$user_Arr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

if ($success_user == 1) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_Arr)) {
            if ($row['email'] == $email) {

                # save user_nr of the registered user to $user_nr
                $user_nr = $row['user_nr'];
            }
        }

        $register = "INSERT INTO registration (
            user_nr,
            user_name, 
            email, 
            etc ...
        ) VALUES (
            '$user_nr', 
            '$name $firstname' , 
            '$email', 
            etc ...
        )";

        if (mysql_query($register) === TRUE) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['infotext'] = "Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error();
        }
}
```

After this I check my database and `user_nr` is set to the right number in `users`.

In the `registration`-table `user_nr` is always 0 the first time the user registers but all other data is correct.

If the same user registers again for a second couse, the users data is getting updated by:

```
$update_user = 
    "UPDATE kunden SET 
        name='$name',
        firstname='$firstname',
        etc ...
        # no redefinition of the email here
    WHERE email='$email'";

if (mysql_query ($update_user) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['infotext'] = "Registration successfull";
}
```

After this the new registration for the same user holds the right `user_nr` in its data in the `registration`-table.

It seems like the call for `users WHERE email='$email'` does not get the - just queried value from the database

**Do I need to wait for the first query to be completed at some point?**

**Or are mysql_queries executed after the script finished?**

**--> Why is the `user_nr` always 0 the first time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

I fetched the user data in my code via `$user_Arr` before adding the new user.
So the new user was not in the data `$user_Arr` got.

So if you add something to your database be shure to **refetch the data after adding something**.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without debugging but i suspect that

```
 if ($row['email'] == $email) {
            # save user_nr of the registered user to $user_nr
            $user_nr = $row['user_nr'];
        }
```

($row['email'] == $email) comparison is not correct.  Try to printout the $email and $row['email'] to see if they have proper data
 like

```
echo "row['email'] : ".$row['email']." email:".$email. " Comp:" . ($row['email'] == $email) : "TRUE":"FALSE";
```

Comment: echoed `$row['email']`, `$email`, and a var for comparison (`$email == $foundemail`). But I got the same values ans `1` for the comparison. So this should be working, right?

Comment: can you echo  the INSERT statement ? Just quite sure you are missing id at this step

Comment: Do you mean the user_nr? Or what do you meen by "id"?

Comment: Found the answer. It's not traceable by the code I gave. Sorry for that.

Comment: well, happy you found the problem